# Elegant approach to handle dynamic HTML classes in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a custom MVC HTML Helper method, like so:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Div (this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
VehicleStatusViewModel vehicleStatus, string classType)
```

I call this helper method to help me choose the right bootstrap class to use for a div in my view. Inside the method, I use a switch to iterate through the possible states of vehicleStatus and assign the according bootstrap class. I.E. panel panel-success if vehicleStatus = 1 or panel panel-danger if vehicleStatus = 2.

However, I may want to assign a particular glyphicon, again, based on a certain returned status of VehicleStatus. In the future, I may have even more additional class types.

In my view, when I call this Helper method, I want to pass a classType (i.e panel or glyphicon). And in my Helper method, without having to duplicate my switch code for each possible class-type, I want an **elegant solution to render the particular classType my View** is requesting and return a TagBuilder div with the appropriately assigned class/class-type, such that:

```
@Html.Div(vehicleStatus, "panel")
// Would resolve and return, if vehicleStatus was 1: 
<div class="panel panel-success"> </div>

// Calling the same method, vehicleStatus = 1 but expecting a respective
// glyphicon:
@Html.Div(vehicleStatus, "glyphicon")
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your description of the problem sounds like a perfect example of either a base-class or interface setup (the possibility to add additional class types in the future by overriding behavior of a base class and/or implementing the interface differently).

This may or may not be what your looking for. I've used similar patterns before, typically in a domain, but sometimes for Razor purposes. In this case, a base class could be used. After finishing, I realized I slightly over-engineered this example. You could probably easily get away with 2 levels until you reach a point you desire more.

```
public abstract class HtmlTag
{
    private readonly String _tag;

    //allow different type of tags to be rendered
    protected HtmlTag(String tag)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tag)) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or whitespace.", "tag");
        _tag = tag;
    }
    //require a VehicleStatus for rendering to an HtmlString
    public String ToHtmlString( VehicleStatus vehicleStatus )
    {
        var tag = new TagBuilder( _tag );
        this.CreateTag( tag, vehicleStatus );
        return tag.ToString();
    }
    //require subclasses to implement the CreateTag method
    //this method will allow subclasses to modify the tag builder as needed
    //depending on the vehicle status
    protected abstract void CreateTag( TagBuilder tagBuilder, VehicleStatus vehicleStatus );
}
```

And, then if you specifically wanted a `div` or a `span`, for example:

```
public abstract class Div : HtmlTag
{
    protected Div( )
        : base( "div" )
    {
    }
}
public abstract class Span : HtmlTag
{
    protected Span()
        : base("span")
    {
    }
}
```

And finally, all you need to do is create classes that implment the CreateTag method:

```
public class PanelDiv : Div
{
    protected override void CreateTag( TagBuilder tagBuilder, VehicleStatus vehicleStatus )
    {
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass( "panel" );
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass(vehicleStatus == VehicleStatus.Success 
            ? "panel-success" 
            : "panel-danger");
    }
}
public class GlyphiconDiv : Div
{
    protected override void CreateTag( TagBuilder tagBuilder, VehicleStatus vehicleStatus )
    {
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass( "glyphicon" );
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass( vehicleStatus == VehicleStatus.Success 
            ? "glyphicon-remove-circle" 
            : "glyphicon-add-circle" );
    }
}
```

If you wanted to add another type, all you'd need to do is:

```
public class MyOtherDiv : Div
{
    protected override void CreateTag( TagBuilder tagBuilder, VehicleStatus vehicleStatus )
    {
        //adjust the tag here based on vehicle status
    }
}
```

And lastly, your HtmlHelper:

```
public static class DivHtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString Div( this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, VehicleStatus vehicleStatus, HtmlTag htmlTag )
    {
        //simply return the HtmlString representation of your HtmlTag you passed in
        return new HtmlString( htmlTag.ToHtmlString( vehicleStatus ) );
    }
    //call this method likeso (from a view):
    //@Html.Div(vehicleStatus, new PanelDiv());
    //@Html.Div(vehicleStatus, new GlyphiconDiv());
}
```

If you find yourself doing the same conditions over and over again, you could slightly refactor the parent class to handle more of the responsibility:

```
public abstract class Div : HtmlTag
{
    private readonly String _className;
    private readonly String _trueCssClass;
    private readonly String _falseCssClass;

    protected Div( String className, String trueCssClass, String falseCssClass )
        : base( "div" )
    {
        _className = className;
        _trueCssClass = trueCssClass;
        _falseCssClass = falseCssClass;
    }
    //the div will use the constructing parameters to populate the classes instead
    protected override void CreateTag( TagBuilder tagBuilder, VehicleStatus vehicleStatus )
    {
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass( _className );
        tagBuilder.AddCssClass( vehicleStatus == VehicleStatus.Success 
            ? _trueCssClass 
            : _falseCssClass );
    }
}
//and your subclass:
public class PanelDiv : Div
{
    public PanelDiv()
        : base( "panel", "panel-success", "panel-danger" )
    {
    }
}
```

If this isn't what your looking for, let me know.

Comment: Thank you James for a very thorough answer! I will go over the provided solution in greater detail tomorrow. I also noticed using TagBuilder may not be the best for divs since they are typically nested, and although you can use TagRenderMode.StartTag, i noticed that at compile-time it cannot properly resolve as it only sees the manually added closing div tag. Any further suggestions on this? Otherwise I will try your suggestions using a StringBuilder tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: I use a custom HtmlTagBuilder I've made over the past year or so. I've never gotten around to publishing it publicly to a repository, but I figured why not. This is what I use (slowly updating it over time): https://bitbucket.org/ThunderSizzle/thunder.helpers/src/31f1ed8ec99312df208ec1af696207c7258e2e04/Helpers.Html/HtmlTagBuilder.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default. There's some performance optimizations that could be done, but I haven't come across anything that called for a major optimization of the current code yet. I don't have any documentation right now, so sorry, though.

Comment: Alright, for some reason, I decided to spruce up an example of using the HtmlTagBuilder (along with adding an untested feature; so obviously use after thorough testing, etc). You can see a version that would allow you to add html inside (from a Razor view; like Html.BeginForm() does). I've personally wanted that feature for a while, just never got around to it. You can see it here: https://bitbucket.org/ThunderSizzle/thunder.helpers/src/9a65c64cf78a34077f0807856c4bde92eafb480d/Thunder.Helpers.Examples/VehicleStatusExample/VehicleStatusModels.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default